# Use existing function declaration as a type, without requring typedef in C

Tags: c, windows

I am writing a program which dynamically resolves the address of some Windows API functions, such as the [`InternetConnectA` function of the `wininet.dll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetconnecta).

The exact details are irrellevant, the point is I have a function which gives me an `LPVOID` to the desired Windows API function, which I can then cast to a function pointer and call like the normal Windows API:

```c
#include <Windows.h>

typedef HINTERNET(*InternetConnectA_t)(
    HINTERNET hInternet,
    LPCSTR lpszServerName,
    INTERNET_PORT nServerPort,
    LPCSTR lpszUserName,
    LPCSTR lpszPassword,
    DWORD dwService,
    DWORD dwFlags,
    DWORD_PTR dwContext
    );

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    InternetConnectA_t internet_connect_a = (InternetConnectA_t) find_function("wininet.dll", "InternetConnectA");
    internet_connect_a(...);
}
```

The `find_function` method internally parses the PE headers to find the address of the function inside `wininet.dll`.

However, using this method, I currently need to manually declare a `typedef` for every function I want to use (or specifiy the type inline). But since I already include the `Windows.h` header, which contains function declarations for all these methods, I am wondering if I could use them to tell the compiler "Please treat this address as having the same function signature as the declaration of InternetConnectA", removing the need for an extra `typedef`.

The following code **does not work** but might explain want I am attempting to do:

```c
#include <Windows.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    InternetConnectA* internet_connect_a = (InternetConnectA*) find_function("wininet.dll", "InternetConnectA");
    internet_connect_a(...);
}
```

In that snippet, the compiler would then look the declaration of "InternetConnectA" and use that signature as the type for the pointer.

I understand that function overloading would introduce ambiguity to the function name, however that should only become a problem when using C++, since there is no function overloading possibilities in C (to my knowledge).

Comment: I'm having trouble with the objective here.  If you know what function you are calling, so as to be able to use its name to determine the signature, then why are you not using its name to call it directly?

Comment: @JohnBollinger OP's `find_function()` seems to be the equivalent of [`dlopen/dlsym`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) - they happen to have the signature of the function by way of Windows.h, but not the actual function to call at compile time.

Comment: I recognize the parallel with `dlopen()`, @AKX, but they say they are looking up the functions specifically in a standard Windows system DLL.  As far as I can determine, then, they are not just looking for functions with the same signature as functions declared in Windows.h, they are looking for the actual Windows functions themselves.  And in that case, again, I do not understand why they are choosing an indirect approach -- at considerable effort -- instead of the ordinary direct one.

Comment: Maybe they're writing a Wine competitor? :) (Or, more broadly, just don't have anything to call at compile time for some reason, and no import libraries at hand either...)

Comment: @JohnBollinger Indeed, I am looking for the actual function. However, I am writing fully position independent code for use in shellcode, so that means I cannot rely on the Windows PE loader to load the libraries and resolve the addresses, so I need to do it manually at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Well,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

typedef typeof(foo)* foo_func_p;

int main() {
    foo_func_p x = (foo_func_p)foo;
    printf("%d", x(1, 5));
}
```

[works](https://godbolt.org/z/h6jEzb4j1) (though I'm advised this is not standard C), so I'd imagine you could get away with

```
typedef typeof(InternetConnectA)* InternetConnectA_p;
// ...
InternetConnectA_p* internet_connect_a = (InternetConnectA_p) find_function("wininet.dll", "InternetConnectA");
```

to avoid typing out the typedef yourself.

Sure, if you want to get rid of the typedef altogether,

```
typeof(InternetConnectA)* internet_connect_a = (typeof(InternetConnectA)*) find_function("wininet.dll", "InternetConnectA");
```

should work too, but that's a mouthful...

Comment: That may well work in Visual Studio, but `typeof` is not standard C.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Works in clang and gcc, see godbolt link.

Comment: It may work with clang, too, depending on the command-line arguments.  It's still not standard C.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sure. Added a disclaimer to say it's not standard C.

Comment: There's a similar [`decltype`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/decltype-cpp?view=msvc-170) keyword that's now in standard C++. (I don't know about C, though.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, this does not seem to work in msvc / Visual Studio, even with /permissive, as per your godbolt example.
(edit: I am aware of the extremely unusual setup, but unfortunately I do need to compile on Windows using msvc)

Comment: @JohnBollinger — note that `typeof` and `typeof_unqual` will probably be a part of C23 — see [N3054](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3054.pdf), a close to final version of C23.

Comment: I do so note, @JonathanLeffler, and was already aware.  But C23 is not published yet.